# How to Diagnose and Fix Freezing For A few Seconds Every Few Minutes

Tags: 18.04

Every few minutes my Ubuntu desktop freezes for a few seconds.  I can move my mouse but clicking and the keyboard have no obvious effect.

While this is happening I see the following in my logs:

```
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) AIGLX: Suspending AIGLX clients for VT switch
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVLeaveVT is called.
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:75
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 226:0
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:69
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:66
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:68
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:67
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:65
May 11 15:04:07 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got pause for 13:64
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 13:75
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) systemd-logind: got resume for 226:0
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) AIGLX: Resuming AIGLX clients after VT switch
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): NVEnterVT is called.
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): EDID vendor "DEL", prod id 40976
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using hsync ranges from config file
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Using vrefresh ranges from config file
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Printing DDC gathered Modelines:
May 11 15:04:39 bb8 /usr/lib/gdm3/gdm-x-session[29416]: (II) NOUVEAU(0): Modeline "1920x1200"x0.0  154.00  1920 1968 2000 2080  1200 1203 1209 1235 +hsync -vsync (74.0 kHz eP)
```

I installed Ubuntu 18.04 LTS a couple days ago and this has been happening since then -- this was not occurring when I was running Ubuntu 14.04 on the same PC.

Comment: I'm trying out switching from Nouveau display driver to NVIDIA binary driver (nvidia-340) to see if this resolves the freezing for me.

Comment: The OS unfreezes on its own.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When your desktop freezes, write down the exact time.

Either wait for the desktop to unfreeze or ssh into the machine, and then view `/var/log/syslog` for the time that you wrote down it freezing.

In the my case the logs had `NOUVEAU` lines around the time of the freeze, I replaced the Nouveau display driver with the NVIDIA binary driver, and that resolved the intermittent freezes.

Comment: It would be useful to include how to do the driver replacement; it seems this is a common issue with that driver.

Comment: I get entries in the `syslog`, but there's no entry corresponding with the freezes...

Answer (score 2):

For me there was nothing showing in `/var/log/syslog`, however I noticed it happened every time I copied to the clipboard.  Turned out to be a clipboard manager called copyq.  Ran `apt purge copyq && apt install copyq` and the problem went away. This probably isn't helpful to know my solution, but it may be helpful to know the problem isn't always output to the syslog.

Comment: I also had copyq. I reinstalled it and it seems OK for now (even though I didn't had it working when the crashes were happening). I also noticed that sometimes pressing CTRL+C freezes the PC in a similar way while copyq is working.
This was in the log when the freeze happened:
`Window manager warning: Buggy client sent a _NET_ACTIVE_WINDOW message with a timestamp of 0 for 0x6c00001 (Edit - 202)`